# Should this be a view helper or action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an architectural question, no code. I'm trying to output time in the format 8 days ago, 7 days ago, etc. Should I process the original time in the action with an action helper or should I process it in the view with a view helper?

Comment: I have been always wondering why this view helper is not in default view helpers provided by Zend Framework. Everyone has to code it sooner or later. Maybe a proposal is needed for ZF2 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in a view helper. This would allow to use it in many views, and it would be easy to modify the format if needed.

Comment: Not sure I understood "use it in many views". If I do it in an action helper, I can reuse it in many controllers/actions too. Can you also elaborate on this "easy to modify the format if needed"? What I'm intending to do is just call it in the view or action without doing any additional processing in the view or action so what kind of additional modifications you have in mind?

Comment: @jblue. Yes, but displaying information for the user to see is the job for views. Thus, it seems more natural to do the formating of the data in the view helper. Action helpers are more about logic, such as processing requests. For me it just seems more natural to do it as a view helper because formation the time, in this case, is only needed to display it to the user.

Comment: I agree. This thing has to do much more to output, than business logic, and for sure more than controller.